# Нужно ли закрывать ошибки?

Tags: php

Есть на php некоторые ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что если пользователь увидит ошибки? Какие могут быть последствия? Я слышал что это небезопасно, но не понятно почему..?!

Comment: из таких ошибок очевидно раскрывается структура директорий на сервере + имена файлов вплоть до кусков кода из них, что уж точно не повышает устойчивости к взлому

Answer (score 3):

Разумеется, ошибки "закрывать" нужно. Или, выражаясь более корректно - *отключать вывод ошибок на экран на боевом сервере.*

Просто потому что нет ни одной причины этого не делать.

> Что если пользователь увидит ошибки? Какие могут быть последствия?

Пользователь поймет, что сайт делал криворучко, и пойдет искать другой.

> Я слышал что это небезопасно, но не понятно почему..?!

Разумеется, сам факт показа ошибок не сделает тут же сайт уязвимым.

Но при целенаправленной атаке сообщения об ошибках окажут очень большую помощь атакующему. Например, сообщения об ошибках ЗНАЧИТЕЛЬНО облегчают эксплуатацию SQL Injection. [Относительно недавний пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422994/).